# PHP page hacked - mass email was sent from my account

Tags: php, mysql, email

Somehow mass emails were sent from my domain ("mywebsite.de" is here only placeholder). I do not know how that was possible. The only place where I use the mail function is at my password reset form. The user has to enter his name or his email to get a mail with a link to reset the password.

All recipients of the mass-emails are ...@t-online.de and the sender was changed to pantera.hamdi@mywebsite.de

Could you help me where is the weak spot in the code below? How can I make the input form more secure? How could a potential attack look like?

I appreciate your help.

```
<?php
include 'helper_functions.php';

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  
    $login = test_input($_POST["login_var"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE (username=? OR email = ?)";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login , $login);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $email = $row["email"];

    if (!empty($email)) {
        
        // if old entry with that email exists - delete old password reset entry
        $sql =  "DELETE FROM pass_reset WHERE email=?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s", $email,);      
        }
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        
        $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50));

        $sql = "INSERT INTO pass_reset (email,token) VALUES (?,?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss", $email, $token,);      
        }

        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            $FromName = "mywebsite";
            $FromEmail = "test@mywebsite.de";
            $ReplyTo = "test@mywebsite.de";
            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
            $headers .= "From: " . $FromName . " <" . $FromEmail . ">\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $ReplyTo . "\n";
            $headers .= "X-Sender: <" . $FromEmail . ">\n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
            $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
            $headers .= "Return-Path: <" . $FromEmail . ">\n";
            $subject = "You have received a password reset email";


            $mlink = "https://mywebsite.de/password_reset_page.php?token=".$token;
            $msg = "
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Your password reset link</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    Reset your password with this <a href=" . $mlink . "> Link</a>. 
                </body>
                </html>";
            
            if (@mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers,'-f'.$FromEmail)) {
                header("location:forgot_password_page.php?sent=1");
                echo 'email sent';
                $hide = '1';
            } else {
                header("location:forgot_password_page.php?servererr=1");
            }
            
        } else {
            header("location:forgot_password_page.php?something_wrong=1"); 
        }
    } else {
        header("location:forgot_password_page.php?err=".$login); 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the email was actually sent from your server? Anybody can write anything they like in the "From" field of an email without touching your server at all. The only thing you can do is use technologies like SPF, DKIM, and DMARC, which help the *recipient* determine that the message is fake.

Comment: @IMSoP  Yes it was sent from my webserver, because I can see it in my "outbox control". Also my provider claims, that it was sent per "Sendmail" by exploiting above form. However I really do not have a clue how that could happen, because you have to be regestiered in order to get a password-forgot mail.